# Event Reservation with Virtual Location, not physical location

Tags: google-schemas

When setting up an JSON-LD Email Markup for an Event Reservation, the Location of type "Place" is required.

[image]

Is it possible to specify a VirtualLocation type for a Google Meet or Zoom session?

https://schema.org/VirtualLocation

When I test my schema using VirtualLocation, I get the error:

> VirtualLocation is not a valid target type for the location property.
> The type VirtualLocation is not a valid type.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentionned the tool you're using to test, but I guess it's the Markup tester from Google ?
https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/

I feel the tool is maybe bugged ?

Because when I try with this tool
https://search.google.com/test/rich-results

It works fine